# How do I call “application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken” outside of AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I want to save my users tokens id into my database using POST request in Swift.

I use this function

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]

    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings( forTypes: types, categories: nil )

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings( settings )
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application( application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData ) {

    let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )

    let deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString )
        .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet )
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ", withString: "" ) as String

    print("token=" + deviceTokenString )

}
```

Question = How do I call didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken outside of the AppDelegate class?

Comment: You don't call it. The system does.

Comment: And the use of `deviceToken.description` is a massive no no. `description` is meant for debugging. You can't rely on its format.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the app delegate `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` delegate meathod to be called elsewhere in your app by calling

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

But you are not calling this method directly.

Comment: I tried it. A new function definitions but the token not outside AppDelegate.it should be the other way

Comment: So Is your issue just that you don't want to save the device token in the  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken handler? You could always call another function from within that delegate method or post a notification with the device token.

Comment: I want to call these tokens from external files( or from main swift)

Comment: Well, whatever you do, that call will need to be initiated from within the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken delegate meathod.

Comment: @nwales I want to receive `deviceToken` in my calss without using AppDelegate's `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`. I mean, I can call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in  my calss but I don't know how to receive `device token`. Do you know how to do that?